# Bringing functionality to data - how is this called?

Tags: terminology

In many cases we get the data from a database and bring it to our application (data to functionality). However in some designs we do it the other way around, which is favourable in Big Data settings. Examples would be Hadoop MapReduce or Apache Spark.

How do we call the approach to bring fucntionality to data and not the other way around? I remember something like "data location sensitive" or "data location awareness" or some thing like that but can not find the correct term in the internet anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it called `data locality`?. 
So suppose if you have a text file of size 1 GB and you have written a map reduce code to convert all text in that file to upper case then first the file will be broken into chunks and the logic to cover the text to Upper case would be available to each data node. Now the tasktracker on each node would only run the map reduce code the data block/s present on that local node. This is known as data locality.

Comment: That's the one (term). I also found one of the article I thought interesting back then: http://www.bluedata.com/blog/2015/05/data-locality-is-irrelevant-for-hadoop/ (no endorsement on the ideas)